# How can we user NserviceBus with WcfRest using SqlServerTransport?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, nservicebus

I want to create a WCF Rest Application using NserviceBus and also i want use SQLServer transport.

Kindly help me ..Give me some Proper Code

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation? You can find many samples there too.

Answer (score 1):

## NServiceBus V5.x - SQL Transport V2.x

The following sample shows you how to setup the SQL transport:

https://github.com/Particular/docs.particular.net/tree/master/samples/sqltransport-nhpersistence/Version_2.2

## Hosting in IIS

NServiceBus can be hosted in IIS without any issues. Especially with a central broker transport like SQL, RabbitMQ, Azure Storage Queues or Azure Service Bus.

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/#self-hosting-web-hosting

> NServiceBus can be hosted in any web technology that support .NET. This includes:
>
> - ASP.net
> - ASP.MVC
> - WCF
> - Web API
> - NancyFX
> - And many others.
>
> As most web technologies operate in a scale out manner NServiceBus is usually hosted in a "Send-only" manner. In this mode they act as a "forwarder" of messages rather than the "processor". So the handling code (MVC controller, NancyFX module etc) of a given web request simply leverages the Bus send APIs and no processing is done in the web process.

Hosting in IIS does have some concerns as application pools by default don't startup automatically and can be recycled or even stopped. Any messages send to such an IIS hosted endpoint will not be processed until the application pool is started again.

## MVC

The following samples demonstrate how to initialize NServiceBus and how to use it from MVC

http://docs.particular.net/samples/web/asp-mvc-application/
http://docs.particular.net/samples/web/asp-mvc-injecting-bus/